# Add a string inside a configuration file through ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-template

I am in need of adding a new string to one of the configuration file. I have to add say "mycustomimage" with a "," in "images =". So in short, my required output is images= previousimage,mycustomimage

View of mycnf.conf

```
id=1
images=previousimage
```

For this, I tried this code

```
---
- hosts: test_server
  - name: Add new string after "," in images
    lineinfile:
        path: /home/mycnf.conf
        regexp: 'images='
        insertafter: '^,'
        line: mycustomimage
```

Expected output

```
id= 1
images=previousimage,mycustomimage
```

But its not working for me. Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance!
Sid

Comment: Can you provide sample of the expected result?

Comment: Its already mentioned in the question. 
required output is 
images= previousimage,mycustomimage

Comment: Does always your line be `images=previousimage` ?

Comment: Your initial line is `ìmages=previousimage,` (It ends with a coma)? Will ii vary? If it varies, can it contain several images? And in this case, will it always end with a coma? And can it already contain the custom image in a random place?  Please edit your question and give a precise example of your initial config line, describe exhaustively the possible variations if any and the expected result.

Comment: Yes to what ? There are 5 questions in my comment.

Comment: Updated my question. So the answers are - It will not end with a comma. Ever new string should start with a comma. Like for example - ,mycustomimage and there is no issue with places.@Zeitounator

Comment: If it does not end with a coma, then why are your trying to insert after one in your example task ? This is really confusing, hence all my above questions.

Answer (score 1):

From your example

1. You know the final line you want to have in the file is `images=previousimage,mycustomimage`
2. You want to add this line in place of an already existing `image=.*` line if it exists and does not match the final one.

The following will do the job

```
    - name: Replace line if needed
      lineinfile:
        path: /home/mycnf.conf
        regex: images=.*
        line: images=previousimage,mycustomimage
```

Note: If for any reason there is no matching line in your file for the regex, the line will be added at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

This will help

```
- name: replace line
  lineinfile:
    path: myfile.txt
    regexp: "^image="
    line: 'image=previousimage,customimage'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `previousimage` is not known you can do two things:

1.Get this line using `grep`, register to a variable and add the line

```
- name: get line
  shell: grep "^image=" /config/file.something
  register: current_image

- name: update image
  lineinfile:
    path: /config/file.something
    regexp: '^image='
    line: "{{ current_image.stdout }},{{ new_image | default('customimage') }}"
```

2.Create a template for this configuration file and render it every time the playbook run and a change is detected:

```
- set_fact:
    images: <list of images retrieved by lookup or static>

- name: update config.something
  template:
     src: my_template.j2
     dest: /config/file.something
```

The template will look like this:

```
id={{ id }}
images={{ images | join(",") }}
```

Answer (score 1):

We'll assume you don't know what `previousimage` is, that you may have several previous images, and you want to append `mycustomimage`, and you want the playbook to be idempotent:

```
---
- hosts: all
  connection: ssh
  become: no
  gather_facts: no


  vars:
    image_name: mycustomimage

  tasks:
  - lineinfile:
      path: testfile.txt
      regexp: '^images=(.*(?<!{{ image_name }}))'
      line: '\1,{{ image_name }}'
      backrefs: yes
```

So let's explain the regexp: `^images=` you can figure out yourself!

The first parenthesis starts the backref block, and it's going to suck up everything to the end of the line: `.*`

Then, it looks back at what it just sucked in, and makes sure `{{ image_name }}` is not at the end: `(?<!{{ image_name }})`

Finally, we close the backref block with `)`.